# How to debug Visual Studio ANTLR language support?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, antlr

I have installed ANTLR support in Visual studio and added my combined lexer/parser grammar. According to the instructions [here on Github](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs), I have set everything up.

I created a new project. I have a Combined1.g4 file inside the solution explorer, which has 2 child items: `Combined1.g4.lexer.cs` and `Combined1.g4.parser.cs`. I added the simple example from [this blog](https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-with-antlr-in-csharp/).

After building or RMC -> run custom tool on the `.g4` file, no C# is generated. What steps can I take to find the issue ANTLR not generating anything?

Comment: I found [this tutorial on setup more illuminating](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/).  Good luck, and be sure to post your questions here, I love ANTLR4 questions!  Oh and by the way, though I was able to get 2017 Community to run, it took some doing.   Don't go there yet with ANTLR, stay with 2015 or earlier (I use Community 2012 regularly).

Comment: https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs#generated-code The generated files should never appear in Solution Explorer.